# Can i use claris R2000 rd on 14-34T mega range sprocket?

Tags: shimano, derailleur-rear, sprocket

I have sprocket 14-34T with mega range. I planned to change my old (maybe 1990's) shimano tourney rd to shimano claris R2000 medium cage. Some of my local bike shop said that i can replace with claris rd. But, I search a little bit about claris R2000. I found that claris has top sprocket max 13T and top sprocket min 11T. On the other hand my top sprocket have 14T.

Anyone have experience?

Comment: It will work fine, it has to cope with an 8speed usually and my guess is that you have a 7speed freewheel.

Comment: thank you @JoeK , yes i have 7 speed freewheel

Comment: If you imagine that you're starting from the 2nd smallest ring on an 8speed block, that's basically within spec so you're good to go. Have fun.

Comment: thank you for your explanation @JoeK